# asm fetching username: authorizationdata is malformed, empty field

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager, jfrog-container-registry

Here are the steps I did and got the error every time...

1. Created docker registry in jfrog artifactory and added container there.
2. create access token on jfrog artifactory
3. create secret in aws secret manager side (username:  password:). Added Task execution role to add secretsmanager:*
4. create ECS task definition. Add private repository and add secret manager ARN
5. run the task and wait to see NGINX container to run... and finally got below error..

**"asm fetching username: authorization data is malformed, empty field"**

Not sure what wrong i am doing here. Here is the Doc has given by AWS on same. But still not working...

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-private-registry-authentication-support-for-aws-fargate/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

this is my mistake; I added a space after "username " section in AWS SM. once delete that space, it worked immidiate.

Answer (score 0):

Need to write **username** and **password** spelling correctly in key value pair.

[image]